# In laravel application how to configure isSuperAdmin()?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add admin authentication into my application using Gate facades. Basically, I want to do authorization if the user is an admin so he can able to see all the posts if he is a normal user so he can only see his post.I copied this code from laravel official documentation and I did not understand from where isSuperAdmin() come from and how to configure this.

```
Gate::before(function ($user, $ability)
{     
    if ($user->isSuperAdmin())
    {         
        return true;  
    }
});
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Are you getting any errors? Isn't the gate working?

Answer (score 2):

AS you can see, that method is called in the `$user` object. So, you just need to define that logic in your model:

**User.php**

```
public function isSuperAdmin()
{
    /**
     * Here goes your logic to determine which users are "super_admin"
     *
     * For example, in case you have a'is_super_admin' boolean column 
     * in your database, you could do:
     */

     return $this->is_super_admin;
}
```

Comment: So,we need to make changes into user database table.? I mean need to add ay row? Thanks

Comment: @Yasir it was just an example, maybe you have a "roles" relationship in your model that relate the users and the roles table (maybe a many-to-many relationship). So, in that case you could do: `return $this->roles()->where('role', 'super admin')->exists();` Or you calculate a score in base of an specific logic. You could do this in several ways. You get the idea.